# robot framework -Line terminator expected error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

When I try to provide arguments in *** Test Cases ***  line, getting error as "Line terminator expected" ,  Am I missing some plug in or it is syntax error ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you have isn't illegal syntax. I am guessing that the plugin for your IDE has a rule that recommends that `*** Test Cases ***` appears on a line by itself.

From the robot framework user guide:

> The header row can contain also other data than the actual section header. The extra data must be separated from the section header using the data format dependent separator, typically two or more spaces. These extra headers are ignored at parsing time, but they can be used for documenting purposes. This is especially useful when creating test cases using the data-driven style.